# process termination C++

Tags: c++, windows, process, termination

I have the following problem: I have an application (server that never ends) written in C++ running as a service containing inside the main thread also 3 threads (mainly doing IO).

In the main loop I CATCH all possible exceptions.

The process terminated and nothing was printed either by the main loop or by the threads themselves. I saw in the event log that the process stopped with code 1000.

1. Does Windows creates Core files like in unix ?
2. If from the event log I get a memory address, is there any way of knowing in which part in the application it occurred?
3. Maybe this is a clue: at the same time that it happened I started another application (not the same type).

Comment: Note: There are ways the application will terminate without un-winding the stack to main(). see exit(), terminate() and abort(). These functions may be called automatically under certain situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Windows creates Core files like in unix ?

it does not, automatically. however you can enable such a files by 
either implementing it in your code or by using external application
as windbg, or [Dr. Watson](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308538)

> If from the event log I get a memory address, is there any way of knowing in which part in the application it occurred?

There is no way if in general, if you don't keep debug information files (pdb)

> Maybe this is a clue: at the same time that it happened I started another application (not the same type).

this is not helpful information, unless both of the applications are interacted each other

Answer (score 5):

try to set windbg as the postmortem debugger.

1. install [windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.Mspx)
2. from commandline execute "`windbg -I`"
3. start you application, then you when your application get an unhandled exception,
   the windbg will be activated .
4. from windbg use `"kb" or "!uniqstack"` to see the stacktrace.

   [look here for more commands.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx)
   and look [here](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2007/05/16/process-crash-getting-the-dump-manually/) for how to analysis.

and try use SEH:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

DWORD FilterFunction() 
{ 
 printf("you will see this message first.\n");
 return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER; 
} 


int main(char** argv, int c)
{
 __try
 {
  int this_will_be_zero = (c == 9999);
  int blowup = 1 / this_will_be_zero;
 }
 __except ( FilterFunction()) 
 {
  printf("you will see this message\n");
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that `catch(...)` does not intercept everything that can go wrong in your code, unless you are using Structured Exception Handling. Eg

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(char** argv, int c)
{
  try {
    int this_will_be_zero = (c == 9999);
    int blowup = 1 / this_will_be_zero;
  } catch (...) {
    printf("you won't see this message\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: I use in the main :
try {}
catch (exceptiona @e)
catch (exceptionb @e)
catch (exceptionSTL @e)
catch (exceptionBaseMineException @e)
catch (...)

Comment: That was his point, you are only catching C++ exceptions, not Windows and hardware exceptions (SEH).  Look at the __try and __except keywords.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the /EHa compiler switch when building your application in order to catch windows structured exceptions (such as access violation) with the C++ try/catch constructs.

In Visual Studio this is in project properties Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable C++ Exceptions. You want "Yes With SEH Exceptions (/EHa)". I remember reading setting this has some significant drawbacks, although I cannot recall what they were exactly.

Link: [MSDN on C++ exception handling model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx)

Edit: As **whunmr** suggests, directly using structured exceptions is probably better idea than /EHa

Comment: FWIW, I think I'd be Ok with __try / __catch just in main(), but would be leery about littering my code with them (portability and all that). But OP has elsewhere indicated that he is catching in main(), so no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will whatever program you are using as a debugger depending on the setting in:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Auto"="0"
"Debugger"="My_Debugger" -p %ld -e %ld"
"UserDebuggerHotKey"=dword:00000000
```

You can change `My_Debugger` to the full path of whatever program/IDE you are using for debugging.

This is often set to Dr Watson which will create a log entry of the crash which is not what you want.